# Удалить похожие объекты?

Tags: php, массивы, объекты

Массив:

```
$objects = array(
    (object)array('name'=>'Stiven','age'=>25,'variant'=>(object)array('surname'=>'Sigal')),
    (object)array('name'=>'Michael','age'=>30,'variant'=>(object)array('surname'=>'Jackson')),
    (object)array('name'=>'Brad','age'=>35,'variant'=>(object)array('surname'=>'Pit')),
    (object)array('name'=>'Jolie','age'=>35,'variant'=>(object)array('surname'=>'Pit')),
);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($objects);
```

Как удалить объекты, которые имеют одинаковые `variant->surname` и `age`? Точнее не удалить, а оставить один из них, т.е. чтобы таких одинаковых элементов не было в массиве.

Comment: т.е. в данном массиве должен остаться только Пит или Джоли, тут уже зависит от стиля кодинга/решения.

Comment: разрешите поинтересоваться, что за синтаксис такой, (object)

Comment: какойто новомодный учебник....

Comment: прививдение к типу object

Comment: @Heleg: [манипуляции с типами](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting)

Comment: спасибо, что-то я сразу и не допер. не встечал ранее приведения к объекту.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. отсортировать с помощью ф-ии [`usort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php) и собственной ф-ии, сравнивающей по полям `variant->surname` и `age`. Тогда объекты с одинаковыми значениями точно будут подряд;
2. пробежаться [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php) и ф-ей, сохраняющей [статически](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) предыдущие значения `variant->surname` и `age`, с тем, чтобы вернуть `true` только, если значения изменились.

**Upd.** для ленивых: [работающий пример](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gei-8pq).

Comment: давайте еще и `serizalize` ему сделаем, чтобы уж так.. наверняка? Ладно, шучу, спасибо что откликнулись, сам себе ответил, только вопрос новый возник.

Comment: Поленились понять? Вот [работающий вариант](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gei-8pq) — заморочился проверить. Получилось )

Answer (score 2):

тупо перебором:

- бежим по массиву, если элемент первый, то
- копируем элемент
- проверяем наличие элемента в новом массиве
- если нет, копируем элемент и бежим дальше
- если да, то просто бежим дальше
- в заключение делаем unset() исходного массива, если он не нужен

В результате будем иметь массив без дублей

Comment: тупо перебором... тупо 8-чкой. Ничего что нужно свойства объектов сравнивать, а не сами объекты?

Answer (score 2):

[array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php),[array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk.php), [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php), [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php)

Answer (score 1):

Прошу прощение за некропост(нашёл его через гугл)
Мой вариант решения той же проблемы:

```
/**
 * Вернёт только те объекты из массива $bad, которые уникальны по признаку $property
 * @param array $bad
 * @param string $property
 */
function array_object_unique($bad,$property)
{
    foreach ($bad as $k1 => $a)
    {
        foreach ($good as $k2 => $g)
        {
            if ($a->$property == $g->$property)
            {
                continue(2);
            }
        }
        $good[] = $a;
    }
    return $good;
}
```

Хотя вариант ув. [[@sergiks](/users/7161/sergiks)](/users/7161/sergiks) тоже хороший, запустить его в контексте класса не удалось.
**P.s.** Между прочим этот же алгоритм предложил ув.[[@akalend](/users/1094/akalend)](/users/1094/akalend)

Answer (score 0):

Пришел к такому решению:

```
$tmp = array();
foreach ($objects as $item=>$object)
{
    $tmp[$object->variant->surname][$object->age] = $object;
}

print_r($tmp);
```

Все бы хорошо, да вот только как это переделать в прежний массив пока не знаю. (думаюю...) Если у кого есть идеи, плыз хелп.

Comment: Какое же это решение, если оно не решение : ))

Comment: ну значит вопрос остается в силе.